# What's the difference of `Create` API in llvm::IRBuilderBase and llvm::BinaryOperator?

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

I want to implement bianry operation in my toy programming language with LLVM as its backend. In LLVM document, I found the `Create` API in both `llvm::IRBuilderBase` and `llvm::BinaryOperator`:

1. `llvm::IRBuilderBase::CreateAdd`: https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1IRBuilderBase.html#a928603739e0e70713566011d44052a4f
2. `llvm::BinaryOperator::Create`: https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1BinaryOperator.html#a02ce9966395063ac501ecbc1623deda4

I have 2 questions about the `Create` API:

1. It seems that both of these 2 APIs can implement the bianry operations. But I don't know the difference between them.
2. If I want to use `llvm::IRBuilderBase::CreateAdd` API, I need to construct a `llvm::IRBuilder` with a `llvm::Context` and `llvm::Module` first, just like:

```
llvm::Module module;
llvm::Context context(module);
llvm::IRBuilder<> irBuilder(&context);
```

then use `irBuilder.CreateAdd` to generate the binary operation, just like:

```
llvm::Value *v = irBuilder.CreateAdd(left, right);
```

If I want to use `llvm::BinaryOperator::Create` API, since it's a `static` method, I can call it directly, just like:

```
llvm::Value *v = llvm::BinaryOperator::Create(llvm::BinaryOps::Add, left, right);
```

But how does `llvm::BinaryOperator` know which `llvm::Context` or `llvm::Module` it belongs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of them create a BinaryOperator object; IRBuilder calls BinaryOperator::Create(). IRBuilder is just a wrapper around a lot of different Something::Create()s, including BinaryOperator::Create(). I don't know why some people prefer to use the wrapper and others prefer not to. That's largely a matter of taste, I think.

[Create](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1BinaryOperator.html#a02ce9966395063ac501ecbc1623deda4) can find the relevant Module and Context using the [Instruction](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Instruction.html) you gave it: `insertBefore->getModule()` and `insertBefore->getModule()->getContext()`.

Comment: What will happen if the parameter `insertBefore` is null by default ?

Comment: In that case [the instruction is not inserted](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/master/llvm/lib/IR/Instruction.cpp#L28). The source code is quite readable, BTW.